# Create variable for cell location

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a variable for the start location of this cell copy/paste, so I can use it as a reference point for other data.  Is that possible?  I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy

With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
   .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the syntax for saving those ranges as `Range` objects.

```
dim firstRange as Range, secondRange as Range

set firstRange = wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000")

firstRange.copy

With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
    set secondRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    secondRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

If you wanted the 1st cell for one of those ranges, it would be like this:

`firstRange.Cells(1,1)`

Comment: + 1 :) @Mike: If you wish you may select this post as an answer to your question :)

Comment: +1 @DanielCook The simplest of all makes the best answers at times :)

Answer (score 2):

You already have the answer but also what can be nice is to avoid the clipboard altogether with something like this:

```
Sub WithoutClipboard()

'define the two ranges variables
Dim firstRange As Range
Dim secondRange As Range

'set the range variables to specific ranges
Set firstRange = wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000")
With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
    Set secondRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With

'resize the second range so it exactly the same size as the first range
With firstRange
      Set secondRange = secondRange.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
End With

'move the data without having to use copy/paste
secondRange.Value = firstRange.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Ooo I do like using .value instead; didn't even think about that in this case.  Thank you as well!